# Whitelisting objects using select

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq, whitelist

I'm trying to filter lists using `contains` function, provided by jq. **My input**,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I have a **"whitelist"**:

```
[3, 4, 7]
```

I need to filter input list through whitelist. **Expected output**:

```
[3, 4]
```

I'm able to filter comparing a single item:

```
jq --compact-output --null-input '[1,2,3,4,5] | map(select(. | contains(3)))'
[3]
```

I tried this:

```
$ jq --compact-output --null-input '[1,2,3,4,5] | map(select([3,4,7] | contains([.])))'
[]
$
```

Here `[3,4,7] | contains([.])` intents to pose question:

> is `[.]` a sublist of list `[3,4,7]`?

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

**How do I filter using a whitelist**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter you'd use with `contains` is:

```
map(. as $x | select([3,4,7] | contains([$x])))
```

Your attempt uses . incorrectly.

#### Using index/1

For this type of problem, it might be better to use `index/1` than `contains` or its inverse, `inside`. The reasons stem from both semantic and efficiency considerations.

If the whitelist is available as $whitelist and if you want to use map(select(...)), an appropriate filter would be:

```
map( . as $x | select($whitelist|index($x)))
```

For long arrays, this of course is very inefficient. For such arrays, you will almost surely want to look at alternatives, such as using `bsearch` (binary search), or a JSON object (hash).

#### def ix:

The current implementation of `index/1` is less than ideal for the present purpose, but it is fast because it is written in C.  Here's an alternative definition that assumes the availability of `any/2`:

```
def ix(x): any(.[]; .==x);
```

Comment: despite me finding a workaround a few moments I've posted the question, I am accepting your answer as it helped me advance my understanding of the matter. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed `contains` for `inside` and it seems to work now:

```
$ jq --compact-output --null-input '[1,2,3,4,5] | map(select([.] | inside([3,4,7])))'
[3,4]
$
```