# jq - retrieve values from json table on one line for specific columns

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm trying to get cell values from a json formatted table but only for specific columns and have it output into its own object.

json example -

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":409363222161284,
         "rowNumber":1,
         "cells":[
            {
               "columnId":"nameColumn",
               "value":"name1"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"infoColumn",
               "value":"info1"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"excessColumn",
               "value":"excess1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":11312541213,
         "rowNumber":2,
         "cells":[
            {
               "columnId":"nameColumn",
               "value":"name2"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"infoColumn",
               "value":"info2"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"excessColumn",
               "value":"excess2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":11312541213,
         "rowNumber":3,
         "cells":[
            {
               "columnId":"nameColumn",
               "value":"name3"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"infoColumn",
               "value":"info3"
            },
            {
               "columnId":"excessColumn",
               "value":"excess3"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Ideal output would be filtered by two columns - **nameColumn**, **infoColumn** - with each row being a single line of the values.

Output example -

```
{ 
  "name": "name1",
  "info": "info1"
}
{
  "name": "name2",
  "info": "info2"
}
{ 
  "name": "name3",
  "info": "info3"
}
```

I've tried quite a few different combinations of things with select statements and this is the closest I've come but it only uses one.

```
jq '.rows[].cells[] | {name: (select(.columnId=="nameColumn") .value), info: "infoHereHere"}'

{ 
  "name": "name1",
  "info": "infoHere"
}
{
  "name": "name2",
  "info": "infoHere"
}
{ 
  "name": "name3",
  "info": "infoHere"
}
```

If I try to combine another one, it's not so happy.

```
jq -j '.rows[].cells[] | {name: (select(.columnId=="nameColumn") .value), info: (select(.columnId=="infoColumn") .value)}'
```

Nothing is output.

** Edit **
Apologies for being unclear with this. The final output would ideally be a csv for the selected columns values

```
name1,info1
name2,info2
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON - `nameColumn` and all the column should be in quotes `"nameColumn"`

Comment: That's a typo, I changed it from a longer random int will fix for the example.

Comment: It would be helpful to the SO audience if you could be clearer about the required format for the output. You might like to review the [mcve] guidelines if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you would want the output to be grouped by row, so let's first consider:

```
.rows[].cells
| map(select(.columnId=="nameColumn" or .columnId=="infoColumn"))
```

This produces a stream of JSON arrays, the first of which using your main example would be:

```
[
  {
    "columnId": "nameColumn",
    "value": "name1"
  },
  {
    "columnId": "infoColumn",
    "value": "info1"
  }
]
```

If you want the output in some alternative format, then you could tweak the above jq program accordingly.

If you wanted to select a large number of columns, the use of a long "or" expression might become unwieldy, so you might also want to consider using a "whitelist". See e.g. [Whitelisting objects using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833974/whitelisting-objects-using-select)

Or you might want to use `del` to delete the unwanted columns.

### Producing CSV

One way would be to use `@csv` with the -r command-line option, e.g. with:

```
| map(select(.columnId=="nameColumn" or .columnId=="infoColumn")
      | {(.columnId): .value} )
| add
| [.nameColumn, .infoColumn]
| @csv
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and my beginning information could have certainly been better but I'm afraid I was lacking a bit of sleep. 

The end response would be a csv of the cell values - I'm not sure why I didn't just say that last night but I'll edit it accordingly.

Your above reply is producing the stream as expected but now I realize I want it as a csv

Comment: I managed to get this to where it works at least with the following 

`.rows[].cells | map(select(.columnId=="nameColumn" or .columnId=="infoColumn")) |[.[].value]|@csv`

Comment: Please see update.  Be careful with .[] as that assumes the ordering of keys is uniform.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help!